# DSA generate signature and verify

Tags: dsa

I'm trying to generate a signature for DSA with the following parameters:

$p = 23$ , $q = 11$ , $g = 3$ , $H(m) = 8$ , $x = 5$

for the life of me, I cannot choose a random $k$ ($0 > k > q$) that will give me $r$ , $s$ that 'add up' when calculating $w$, $u1$, $u2$, and verifying.

I don't know if I'm just doing my maths wrong, but I've tried every possible $k$ between $0$ and $11$ and I just can't get $v = r$ at the end of verification.

can someone please please help and show your working out if possible?

Comment: What is the signature you produced, and what is the private key ($x$)?

Comment: @B-Con oops I forgot to give the private key. x=5. as for the signature - I have produced multiple ones while attempting to find a value of k that 'adds up' when calculating v. I think I may be doing something wrong in the calculations because surely at least one value > 0 < 11 must work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, back to my initial answer (which I edited to the last version, thinking that you did not choose an appropriate generator):

I now think that you may calculate the inverses wrongly:

I tried it with $k=2$ and get:

$r=9,k^{-1}=6, s=10, w=10, u_1=3, u_2=2$ which works out.

Just as an additional comment:

**Choosing a generator**

Since the order $11$ is prime, you can simply choose an arbitrary element of $Z_{23}^*$, say $h$, and then compute your $g$ as $g=h^{22/11} \pmod{23}$, i.e., every element that lies in this subgroup is a generator of this subgroup.

Take for instance $h=2$ and compute $g=h^{2}\pmod{23}=4$ (in your case, $3$ is also fine).

**General case:** For the general case $Z_p^*$ with $p$ being prime, an element $g$ is a generator if it holds that all for all prime divisors of the order $p-1$ the following holds:

$g^{(p-1)/q_i}\neq 1 \pmod{p}$.

Typically, you construct $p$ as a safe prime, i.e. choosing prime $q$ and set $p=2q+1$ as, then you know the prime divisors $2$ and $q$ by construction.

Comment: hi! thank you so much for answering. I see what you're saying and I had not thought of it before. HOWEVER, this is revision I am doing and the question is on a worksheet given to the class. I didn't choose g... they gave us the value for g, p, q, x and H(m). That's why I said I couldn't come up with a suitable value for k... the only value they didn't specify in the question.

Comment: Then you should point out that the worksheet is buggy ;)

Comment: are you sure?? I mean, the very first question in this set is to show that g has order q as required. our lectures say to calculate this by showing that: $g^q$ mod $p$ = $1$ . which it does... $3^1$$^1$ mod $23$ = $1$ . So how can it be wrong?

Comment: You are right, I thought this would be the mistake. But actually, I think you may make some errors when computing multiplicative inverses?

Comment: sorry but... how do you get $6$ from $2^{-1}$??

Comment: in order to compute $2^{-1}\pmod{11}$ you need to find $x$ such that $2\cdot x=1\pmod{11}$, which is the definition of the multiplicative inverse. Now you can use extended euclidian (in the general case, here your brain should suffice), to figure out that $x=6$ since $2\cdot 6= 1\pmod{11}$. Consequently, $2^{-1}=6 \pmod{11}$.

Comment: ok so we're computing $2^1 (mod$ $11)$ ... but... why? why $(mod $ $11)$ ? I'm sorry if this is a noob question but I $am$ new to crypto haha. the function for $s$ is $s = k^{-1} (H(m) - x$ x $r) mod$ $q$ right? so why should we calculate $k^{-1}$ as $k^{-1} (mod$ $q)$ ?

Comment: because we are working in the field $Z_{11}$. You should take a look at modular arithmetic and basic algebra.

Comment: actually I figured it out shortly after I posted that. but I couldn't edit any more. it was obvious hahah. BUT I think I have identified the next obvious error (besides doing the inverse wrong).... it's not $H(m) **-** x$ x $r$ , it's $H(m) **+** x$ x $r$ right?? now this isn't my fault.. $H(m) **-** x$ x $r$ is what the LECTURES say. so I think they may be wrong?

Comment: Actually, I do not now your lecture notes/slides. But, yes it should be $s=k^{-1}(H(m)+rx)\pmod{q}$. Thats how it is standardized in DSS. But if you take $s=k^{-1}(H(m)-rx)\pmod{q}$ it should work by replacing $y^{u_2}$ (as it is in the standard) by $y^{-u_2}$ in the verification equation.

Comment: ahhh well yes, they do say $y^{-u2}$... so in that case, what would $s$ be??

Comment: alright! so $r=9$ $s=9$ $w=5$ $u1=7$ $u2=1$ and BAM! it all works out to $9$ so $v=r$! correct right? so the error was simply the calculation of the inverse all along?

Comment: yes, error was simply in calculating the wrong inverses.